# jquery UI button too width although padding = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, button

I try to reduce the width of some of my jQuery buttons. I use the following code to remove the padding, but there are still at least 5 pixels to the left and right of the text in my button.

```
.button().css({ 'padding-left':'0px', 'padding-right':'0px' });
```

When I change the '0px' to '200px' for example I end up with a really width button, so the code should be correct in general and target the right element.

Comment: just `.css('padding','0');` or `.css({'padding-left':'0','padding-right':'0'});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because the  element that's inside the button has it's own padding. Here's the CSS generated from jQuery UI's buttons:

```
.ui-button-text-only .ui-button-text {
    padding: .4em 1em;
}
```

Just tried removing that 1em Left & Right padding and it worked. Hope that helps!